# Webmail account - emails content has disappeared

Tags: webmail

I have a webmail account with mail.com. A few days ago, I found all emails in my inbox (read and unread) have the same content: the word "forbidden" in text format, and nothing else, any original content has disappeared. Of course this looks like hacking, but I know mail.com had a server maintenance around 21st January. Anyway, I tried using a special form to contact them, but nothing happened, the form didn't get sent away.

What should I do now? I depend heavily on this mailbox.

Comment: Mail.com has other peculiar characteristics. Their homepage does not always show the login box (always the sign up box however) - sometimes it does, and sometimes it does not, and this does not seem to depend on the browser I am using.

Comment: What "special form" did you use to try to contact them? How do you know the form didn't get sent?  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that *the access* was forbidden - temporarily or permanently, for unknown reason; not necessarily the mails are gone. You are just forbidden to see them.

Contact them why you are locked, or simply try again after some hours.

And maybe make a backup, when you have access again.